# section a href not working on safari and firefox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, location-href

I have using a href to navigate to another section on the same page. It works like a champ on chrome but doesn't work on safari. Please help me find the issue.

uses.vue

```
For more information, please <a href="#section1">click here</a>
For more information about monitors, please <a href="#section2">click here</a>.

<div id="section1">        
 <p>
  <b> 1.Uses of CPU</b>
 </p>
</div>
<div id="section2">        
 <p>
  <b> 2.Types of monitors</b>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try running your page through an HTML validator: https://html5.validator.nu/. Do you have multiple elements with the same id? (Also, is this all the HTML it takes to reproduce the problem? If not, try removing parts of your page, like scripts, until it stops happening. Post the smallest version in your question as a [mcve].)

Comment: I checked it. no same ids.

Comment: The links work the second time I click on it. But not the first time